# Sign in the Free Propagator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, propagator

The free propagator in Zee's book for free scalar field theory is
$$D(x-y)=\int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{\exp[ik(x-y)]}{k^2-m^2+i\epsilon}.$$

He then says that the sign of $k$ in the exponential does not matter here by the symmetry $k \rightarrow -k$. Why is that? Where does this symmetry explicitly come from?

Answer (score 2):

It can be attributed to the fact that the corresponding free Lagrangian density ${\cal L}$ only contains terms with an even number of spacetime derivatives.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{\exp[ik(x-y)]}{k^2-m^2+i\epsilon} = \frac{\cos(k(x-y)) + i\sin(k(x-y))}{k^2-m^2+i\epsilon}
$$
The $k$ odd $sin$ part drops out upon integration, leaving only the $k$ even $cos$ part. Therefore, the sign of $k$ does not matter.